# Python Pandas change column values to NULL and return to its original values

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am creating on a Python script that will automate in changing the column values to `NULL` before sending it via e-mail.

My goal is to temporarily change some column values due to its confidential data. Here is what it looks like:

```
svc_no   last_name   first_name   acc_no     some_column
12345    Parker      Peter        1111111    some_value
11111    Stark       Tony         2222222    some_value
22222    Rogers      Steve        3333333    some_value
```

I have multiple Excel files and I will be sending the Excel files to someone. That someone will be doing some processing on those Excel files but before I send it via e-mail, I need to change some column values to `NULL` due to its confidentiality.

My desired output will be like this:

```
svc_no   last_name   first_name   acc_no     some_column
12345    NULL        NULL         NULL       some_value
11111    NULL        NULL         NULL       some_value
22222    NULL        NULL         NULL       some_value
```

Here is what I did:

1. I iterate all the files and get the path of the directory to back-up all the Excel files which I plan to use as a reference for later in returning the original values of the columns. I used **os**,* shutil** and **glob** libraries.

   ```
   path = os.path.absolute(__file__)
   new_path = path + 'source'

   files = []

   if not os.path.exists(new_path):
       os.makedirs(new_path)

   for file in files:
       if file not in new_path:
           shutil.copy(file, new_path)
   # line continue in number 2 list
   ```

These codes will create a folder in the same directory as the script and copy the all the Excel files in the newly created directory which is `new_path`.

2. Now, I declare each Excel file to be a DataFrame and change the column values to `NULL` using `.loc`:

   ```
           df = pd.read_excel(file)
           df.loc[df['l_name'].notnull(), 'last_name'] = 'NULL'
   ```

I also tried inserting a column that contains `NULL` values and copy the it to the desired column using `iloc` although nothing also happened. It also did not create the column.

```
df.insert(loc=5, column='empty_column', value='NULL')
df.iloc[:,1] = df.iloc[:,5]
```

My problem is that it doesn't change the `last_name` column values to `NULL`. Is there another way to this?

I have already used `.iloc` and `.loc` in some of my projects and they are working but I am confused here why they are not doing anything.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: But did you try `df[ 'last_name'] = 'NULL'`?

Comment: @DYZ I tried it right now. Also nothing happned.

Comment: What do you mean but 'nothing happens'? definetly something is happening. How are you evaluating if your changes are actually being made? For example, if you just `read_excel`, and change the `df`, the excel file will remain unchanged (you have to `df.to_excel` so its saved).

Comment: This is somewhat hard to believe because this operation is truly basic. Are you checking the DataFrame or the Excel file? The file will not change unless you write the DataFrame back to disk.

Comment: @DYZ I'll try saving it to df.to_excel(). I think my problem is that I am thinking that the changes are happening in the same excel file that the iteration is currently in.

Comment: Once you read the content of an Excel file into a DataFrame, you have two copies of the content. Changing one does not change the other.

Comment: @DYZ I got to understand it a lot better now. It's actually working and I am just looking at the wrong file. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see the issue here. You seem to be overcomplicating things. Would this not suffice:

```
df

0   12345   Parker  Peter   1111111 some_value
1   11111   Stark   Tony    2222222 some_value
2   22222   Rogers  Steve   3333333 some_value
```

Create a confidential version:

```
confidential_columns = ['last_name', 'first_name', 'acc_no']

confidential_df = df.copy()
confidential_df[confidential_columns] = 'NULL'
```

You get this:

```
confidential_df

0   12345   NULL    NULL    NULL    some_value
1   11111   NULL    NULL    NULL    some_value
2   22222   NULL    NULL    NULL    some_value
```

Then decide which on to write based off of some decision:

```
confidential = True

def write()
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
    if confidential:
        confidential_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='report')
    else:
         df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='report')

write()
```

I'm not going to deal with path/file/directory management when it comes time to write because that seems like it's out of the scope of your issue.